# Minimizing Absolute Value

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, linear-diophantine-equations

Let a, b, c be three nonzero integers satisfying 7a + 11b + 13c = 0. What is the least possible value of |a| + |b| + |c|?

I tried graphing this on the x-y-z plane but that didn't help much as a, b, and c are integers. Could anyone explain how to solve this? I would also like to know the general strategy for solving this type of problem for the future.

Comment: I think the minimum is $6$, achieved when $a=1, b=-3, c=2$, but I can't come up with a proof. I believe a good way to start would be to solve the Diophantine equation and parametrize the solutions.

Comment: How would you parametrize the solutions? I don't think Bézout's would exactly work here.

Comment: The method as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970287/how-to-solve-linear-diophantine-equation-with-3-variables should work.